# Ensure query is atomic

Tags: python, postgresql, atomic

**Background**

In my code below I have a function called process that does some stuff and when it is running i want to make sure it is not run concurrently. I have a table called `creation_status` where i set a time stamp anytime i start the process. The reason i use a time stamp is because it allows me to know what time i started this process in case i need to.

I always check if there is already a time stamp and if there is raise an exception to make sure i am not running this script concurrently.

**Code**

```
def is_in_process() -> bool:
    status = db.run_query(sql="SELECT is_in_process FROM creation_status")
    return False if status[0].is_in_process is None else True


def set_status() -> None:
    db.execute(sql="UPDATE creation_status SET is_in_process = NOW()")

def delete_status() -> None:
    db.execute(sql="UPDATE creation_status SET is_in_process = NULL")


def process():
 if is_in_process():
        raise Exception("Must not run concurrent process creations." )
    set_status()
    # stuff happens
    delete_status()
```

**Issue**

I want to make sure my query is **atomic** to eliminate race conditions. It is possible that the by the time i check the function `is_in_process` and call the function `set_status` another script could get kicked off. How do i ensure both those things happen in one go so i avoid race conditions.

Please let me know if i can explain something more clear and i am open to all suggestions.

Comment: Use a transction with an appropriate isolation level?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use multiple steps when you don't need to.

```
UPDATE creation_status SET is_in_process = NOW() where is_in_process is null returning is_in_process
```

Then check to see if a row is returned.

Of course this should probably be done in the same transaction as the rest of the stuff, which we can't tell from your code, but then things will just block until the previous is done, rather than aborting.

Comment: Ah okay that makes sense, and if i understand correctly. In the SQL statement since you are checking the status and then setting it in one statement assures there is no race condition right?

Comment: I guess my question is , is there anything else needed that should be wrapped around the query to make sure it is atomic?